# NiFi - Change Filename (CSV) adding an attribute from a incoming JSON

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to modify the name of some files with NiFi getting a value from a JSON an adding to the original filename (for example filename.csv (original name) + january (name that provides the incoming JSON)). To do so, I am redirecting the CSV files to updateAttribute to change de Filename. 
From the other hand, I am receiving a JSON that has an attribute that will be part of the name of the file.

[image]

On the evaluateJsonPath the configuration is the next (I am receiving it correctly the value):

[image]

And finally I am trying to merge the values in the UpdateAttribute processor **(here is where it doesn't work properly)**:

The response I am getting is **_filename.csv**
[image]

Comment: You said it doesn't work properly, but you haven't said what happens. Is there an error? what is the value of the filename attribute after this update attribute processor?

Comment: question edited

Answer (score 2):

You have quotes around `name` inside your Expression Language expression, try

`${name}_${filename}` or

`${name:append('_'):append(${filename})}`